# How can I setup a vhost that resolves the subdomain "phpmyadmin" on any TLD?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, virtualhost, wildcard

I have a web server with quite a few domains on it. I am looking for an easy way to point specific sub-domains (webmail, phpmyadmin) on any TLD hosted on this server to a folder with the relevant systems using an Apache vhost.

So regardless of what domain, as long as someone enters phpmyadmin as a subdomain it should load the applicable folder.

I have a method to add a cname automatically for each DNS zone, but I'm struggling with Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wildcard `ServerAlias` should do the trick..

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phpmyadmin-handler
    ServerAlias phpmyadmin.*
    # any and all settings needed for phpmyadmin to function..
    DocumentRoot /path/to/phpmyadmin
    <Directory /path/to/phpmyadmin>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: +1 for the obvious yet brilliant solution